# Using variables of equal value as dictionary keys results in overwritten values (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a Python dictionary as below:

```
Mail_Dict = {
        MailList0 : CodeList0,
        MailList1 : CodeList1,
        MailList2 : CodeList2,
        MailList3 : CodeList3,
        MailList4 : CodeList4
}
```

The issue is when one of the MailLists have values that are the same as another MailList (ie: `MailList0 = 'someone@email.com'` and also `MailList1 = 'someone@email.com'`), the keys are treated as equal and `CodeList0` gets overwritten by `CodeList1`, also making my dictionary shorter in the process.

Is there anyway to keep these separate? I would think that the same logic for below:

```
a=1
b=1
```

saving to separate memory addresses and being different from:

```
a=b=1
```

would apply here, but I guess that isn't the case =(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which language is this code in?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention. it's python. edited my post as such.

Comment: It sounds like you need a list of tuples, not a dict.

Comment: Also, your description of "saving to separate memory addresses" sounds like you're working with a bad mental model of Python variables. Ned's guide is a good way to clear things up on that front: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create both the values of the same key in the dictionary, one solution would be to add the old value to a list and append the new value to the list.

```
Mail_Dict = {
    MailList0 : CodeList0,
    MailList2 : CodeList2,
    MailList3 : CodeList3,
    MailList4 : CodeList4
}
```

Now if you want to add MailList1 (which has the same value as MailList0) to the dictionary, check if MailList1 already is a list. if it is not a list make it into a list and then append the new value.

```
if(MailList1 in Mail_Dict):
    if (isinstance(Mail_Dict[MailList1],list)==False):
        Mail_Dict[MailList1] = [Mail_Dict[MailList1]

    Mail_Dict[MailList1].append(codeList1)
```